# How can I disable this scrolling method?

Tags: scrolling

An Ubuntu scrolling method found in many apps is driving me crazy. I call it two step scrolling; you have to place the pointer in a narrow orange bar to start scrolling and then when you put pointer on the down arrow and scroll down you can't actually reach the bottom of the page.

How can I disable this?

[image]
<sub>(source: [axgig.com](https://www.axgig.com/images/06189662640635209529.png))</sub>